# Modify Windows 7 Start menu search algorithm?

Tags: search, windows-7, fuzzy-search, windows-search

I really like the fuzzy matching search algorithm that [Sublime Text 2](http://www.sublimetext.com/) uses for its command palette and I was hoping to create something similar that runs through the Windows 7 Start menu search.

I already found the [Windows API Code Pack for .NET Framework](http://archive.msdn.microsoft.com/WindowsAPICodePack) but that only seems to provide API hooks for using the existing Windows Search inside my own applications.

Is there any way to modify or replace the search algorithm that the Start menu search uses for searching installed applications and files?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I am pretty sure that is not possible. But it shouldn't be hard to program a little something that overlays the search box and (if there is something in the search box) also the results area. With this custom gadget it wouldn't be hard to use any search algo you want.

Comment: It's a damn shame that it's not easily accessible, although I can't imagine many people would care either haha.